# Recompilation of custom KLM module

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, powerpc

I'm new to building and understanding the kernel KLM stuff, could you please clarify below queries?

Say suppose, we have one custom KLM module cust.ko which is built out-side-tree using below build inline command (makefile) against one kernel (dir) which contains 8 KLM modules (built inside kernel source tree)

```
$(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILER) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Question:

If we're re-compiling kernel and instroduced 3 new KLM modules (from menuconfig), do we also need to recompile the cust.ko to load it successfully on top of this newly rebuilt kernel ? If yes, any specific technical reason behind it ?

Is it because the load/init address is hardcoded (somehow computed) when complied against kernel ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled the custom KLM module and things started working as expected. So, I depends on the test results I believe if any KLM is built outside the tree which needs to be recomplied incase any new KLM is added to the KLM and the cust KLM need re-initialization on top the newly built one.

Thanks !